# Copy existing Azure resource group items into another Subscription RG

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-resource-manager, azure-deployment, azure-resource-group

All I want is to copy/recreate all the existing resources which is under resource-grp1 from a Production environment to another resource-grp2.

What would be the **very easiest** way to re-create the same environment in another Resource Group in the same subscription? I tried to export the resource group and downloaded. The problem is that the file “parameters.json” includes hard coded references to the original resource group name. Is there an way to do this without using Azure CLI/Powershell, only use Azure Portal
**resource-grp1** contains following resources

```
 1. 2 app service plans
 2. 10 app services
 3. 8 azure sql database
 4. 3 NSG & vnet
 5. Application Insight
 6. SendGrid
 6. Storage account
 7. VM
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are facing issue with Export template "The problem is that the file `“parameters.json”` includes hard coded references to the original resource group name" try below.

Azure portal - > Resource group -> **Export Template** and *download* the template.

After download the templates (`template.json` and `parameters.json`) files **find** *old resource group reference* and **change** into *new resource group reference*.
[image]

[image]

Deploy into other resource group:

Search **Template Deployment** in Azure portal search bar and click on **create**.

[image]

Click on **Build your own template** in the editor

select **parameter** and add updated `parameters.json` file

&

select **resources** and add updated `template.file` and save it.

[image]

Add *subscription* and *Resource group* which you need to deploy.

[image]

[image]

Click Create it will deploy your resources in a new resource group.

Answer (score 2):

You can just navigate to your Resource group > Click on Export Template from side Panel
You'll have 3 options

1. Download
2. Add to Library
3. Deploy

When **Downloaded,** the ARM Template will be saved to the local machine. This will allow for the template to be manually changed or saved somewhere for it to be retrieved for later use.

When **Saving**, the ARM Template will be saved to a collection accessible from “Browse > Templates” within the Azure Portal. This allows for Resource Group configurations to be saved so they can easily be redeployed later.

When **Deploying**, the ARM Template will be deployed to a new Resource Group. This essentially allows for the Resource Group to be “copied.” This could be useful for easily cloning a Resource Group to easily spin up a separate hosting environment with identical settings.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpvsR.png)

I have Downloaded the template and Imported the template using Template Deployments.

Search for Template Deployments > Build your own template in editor > Load File (Add your downloaded template after unzipping) > Save > Create

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaeLu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPWCI.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzJ59.png)

you can refer this [site](https://blogs.perficient.com/2016/03/31/azure-arm-template-import-and-export-templates-from-portal/) for more